# Youtube - getting information from feed

Tags: php, javascript, json, youtube, youtube-api

I am currently calling a youtube playlist using:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=USERNAME&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=function
```

I was just wondering if there was a more thorough feed, I need to be able to collect how many ratings a video has - whereas this just tells me if ratings are allowed...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any rating details inside the feed you mentioned. Nevertheless, it is possible to request another feed that contains the required information. Here is example code that you can place inside a HMTL page that includes jQuery 1.4 or later:

```
<!-- Don't forget to insert jQuery inside <head> section -->
<ol id="videos">
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processFeed(videosFeed) {
    for (var i = 0; i < videosFeed.data.items.length && i < 10; i++) {
        var item = videosFeed.data.items[i];
        var li = $("<li/>").html("loading data for video id " + item.id + "...").appendTo("#videos");
        $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + item.id + "?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=?", (function(el) {
            return function(videoFeed) {
                el.html(videoFeed.data.title + "<br>Views: " + videoFeed.data.viewCount + "<br>Rating: " + videoFeed.data.rating + " out of 5<br>From: " + videoFeed.data.ratingCount + " ratings");
            };
        })(li));
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=sesame street&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=processFeed"></script>
```

I've set up a [jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wWAdx/). You may also find some useful information [here](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html).

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can get it to return all of the videos? I currently have over 200 videos on my channel, thanks.

Comment: @wonderwoman: you will find the article at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html very useful. In particular the query string parameter `max-results` allows you to specify how many results to retrieve (25 is the default AFAIK). Also you can combine this with the `start-index` parameter to implement "paging" like system such as "page 1 of 8", "page 2 or 8" and so on.